# Datagridview Select all

Tags: c#

the following code works but the code I wrote to select all does not work. does not give any error. this code is not working ( dataGridView2.SelectAll();  )

```
using System.data;
private void CaO()
{
   DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
   new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sayfa1$]", @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\ikinciexcel.xlsx; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'")
  .Fill(tbl);

  DataTable dtCloned = tbl.Clone();
  dtCloned.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(float);

  foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
  {
     dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
  }

  var f = new Form();
  var dgv = new DataGridView 
  {
     DataSource = dtCloned,
     Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
     SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect 
  };

  dtCloned.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CaO >= 9 and CaO <= 11";
  dataGridView2.Controls.Add(dgv);
  dataGridView2.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Why do you add one grid as a child of another grid? Why do you not call `SelectAll`on `dgv`?

Comment: I want to select all the data I have filtered on DGV and record it in a different location.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: does nothing. No error. My goal is to choose all.

Comment: Rather than making copies of the data, you should be using Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SelectAll()` method works fine, but You can't see it on the `DataGridView` object becuase you are calling it from place, where `DataSource` property is binded and selection can't be drawed. First of all change `dataGridView2.SelectAll();` to `dgv.SelectAll();` just like @NineBerry mentioned in comment (datasource is binded to `dgv`). For test please place this line of code just below `dgv.SelectAll();` and place breakpoint (F9) on it:

```
var selectionTest = dgv.SelectedCells;
```

Code execution will stop on breakpoint and after pressing F10 VS will step to another line. Right click on `selectionTest` object and choose "Quick Watch" option. In appeared window you can watch all selected cells in proper collection object structure.

If you want to draw selection on your grid, please add some button to your form and call `dgv.SelectAll();` in it's event mthod. Sample code:

```
private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgv.SelectAll();
}
```

This calling will draw selection on the `dgv` as well.

Conclusion: your code works fine, but you can be a little confused because no selection visual effect is visible as should be when row/cell is selected. Just call it from other place when binding and all other creating operations are completed.

Comment: glad to hear I could help. but read comments below your thread. **NineBerry** have right - i also can't understand why you add new grid to existing... maybe it's task-specific but I can't conclude it from your code and description. **WelcomeOverflow** is also right, but I assume you don't have enough knowledge about it all. for better, clearer and more optimal code of DataGridView object, please read it's specification on MS Docs:  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that MultiSelect of dataGridView2 is set to true:

```
dataGridView2.MultiSelect = true;
```

Comment: it might be another property responsible for the behavior of the selection, this is what I'd be checking first, like the SelectionMode property..